# how to track market url link ? is it possible?

Tags: android, google-play

I have two apps. I have integrated more apps options in one of the apps. I want to track how many clicks i have got in this app. I can track this using website url.

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

but user have to select market url or broswer url. it would reduce downloads.
is there any possible to track the market url link directly?

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

Comment: What do you mean by tracking ? Do you want user to only open the url via the google play store app ?

Comment: To track app opens I would integrate an analytics package like Flurry: http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html

Comment: @Snicolas ya and i want to track clicks